# Why is the load of 'stress' unevenly distributed?

Tags: linux, benchmark

When I used stress to conduct stress testing on my system, I found that there was an issue with the distribution of `CPU` usage. `CPU2` had a much higher usage rate than the other three `CPUs`. Excuse me, is this normal?

I observed for about 10 minutes and all the results were similar.

Executed stress test command::

```
stress -c 4 -m 16 -d 16
```

information of top:

```
CPU0: 45.9% usr 53.8% sys  0.0% nic  0.0% idle  0.1% io  0.0% irq  0.0% sirq
CPU1: 44.0% usr 55.5% sys  0.0% nic  0.1% idle  0.1% io  0.0% irq  0.0% sirq
CPU2: 87.6% usr 11.9% sys  0.0% nic  0.0% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.3% sirq
CPU3: 55.8% usr 44.1% sys  0.0% nic  0.0% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.0% sirq
```

lscpu：

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  BIOS Vendor ID:        Intel(R) Corporation
  Model name:            Intel(R) Celeron(R) J6412 @ 2.00GHz
    BIOS Model name:     Intel(R) Celeron(R) J6412 @ 2.00GHz To Be Filled By O.E.M. CPU @ 1.9GHz
    BIOS CPU family:     15
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               150
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per socket:  4
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:  100%
    CPU max MHz:         2000.0000
    CPU min MHz:         800.0000
    BogoMIPS:            3993.60
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_per
                         fmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse
                         4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l2 cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow flexprio
                         rity ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust smep erms rdt_a rdseed smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect dtherm arat pln
                         pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req vnmi umip waitpkg gfni rdpid movdiri movdir64b md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                   128 KiB (4 instances)
  L1i:                   128 KiB (4 instances)
  L2:                    1.5 MiB (1 instance)
  L3:                    4 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Vulnerabilities:
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Enhanced / Automatic IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Vulnerable: No microcode
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

add /proc/interrupts:

```
cat /proc/interrupts
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
   0:        122          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    2-edge      timer
   8:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    8-edge      rtc0
   9:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    9-fasteoi   acpi
  16:          0          0       1163          0  IR-IO-APIC   16-fasteoi   i801_smbus, mmc0
 120:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI    0-edge      dmar0
 121:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI    1-edge      dmar1
 122:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:1c.0    0-edge      PCIe PME, aerdrv, pcie-dpc
 123:          0          0          0      25032  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:14.0    0-edge      xhci_hcd
 124:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:17.0    0-edge      ahci[0000:00:17.0]
 125:          0          1          0          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0    0-edge      eth0
 126:          0          0        650          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0    1-edge      eth0-TxRx-0
 127:          0          0          0        650  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0    2-edge      eth0-TxRx-1
 128:        648          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0    3-edge      eth0-TxRx-2
 129:          0        658          0          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0    4-edge      eth0-TxRx-3
 NMI:          0          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:      12551      10285      21303      11548   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:          0          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
 IWI:         68         21         68         36   IRQ work interrupts
 RTR:          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
 RES:      12513       3510      14961       3320   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:      12861       2485       1025        889   Function call interrupts
 TLB:         31         48         28         61   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
 DFR:          0          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:          4          5          5          5   Machine check polls
 ERR:          0
 MIS:          0
 PIN:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
 NPI:          0          0          0          0   Nested posted-interrupt event
 PIW:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

Comment: Did you have any other non-trivial workload running at the same time, and does your system have NUMA characteristics (i.e. some memory or I/O devices are best accessible by a particular  CPU)?

Comment: @telcoM I added the result of `lscpu`, which should support `NUMA`.

Comment: @telcoM When I closed `NUMA` and tested it, the result was similar to before it was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 4-core Celeron CPU and just one NUMA node... clearly NUMA is not the explanation here. With those parameters to `stress`, you are creating a complex workload.

You have 4 processes doing pure calculation, while a total of 32 processes are doing effectively memory management, whether in the form of `malloc()`s (16 processes) or disk space allocation management and write caching (16 processes).

It looks like the scheduler may be placing the calculation jobs mainly on core #2, while the other cores are mostly tackling the dual userspace/kernel-space work of memory and disk cache allocations. Probably concentrating the calculation processes to a single core minimizes the need to do L1 cache flushes, and allows them to run essentially without touching anything but L1 caches as much as possible. Since those 4 calculation workers are all running the same tight loop of code, they might just be running one shared copy of it, which could easily fit into the core-specific L1 cache.

All your CPU cores are >99% busy (`usr`+ `sys` meets or exceeds 99% in all cores). Note that cores #0 and #1 are spending more than half of their time running kernel processes, probably related to memory management, disk caching and filesystem space allocation. Don't ignore the `sys` percentages: they are not a subset of the `usr` percentages, but percentages of total time spent, just like the `usr` percentages are.

The `io`, `irq` and `sirq` percentages are all negligible, suggesting that all this activity is essentially never hitting the actual disk and just keeping the disk write cache very, very busy.

Comment: Why does it seem that the scheduler may primarily focus on core #2 every time I test?

Comment: All your cores have ~100% usage rate, it's just that on the other cores it consists of about half user-space and half kernel-space work. Why core #2 seems to be getting the "easy" user-space-only calculation processes is harder to say. Perhaps that core has comparatively few IRQs assigned to it, and so it's the best choice for such jobs? Check `/proc/interrupts` to see how hardware interrupts are distributed across the cores.

Comment: I added the results for `/proc/interrupts`. If I add a process in the application layer later and want to bind a CPU, should I bind it to core #2 or non core #2 for my computer?